# Lucky number assignment

Tags: python

Assignment output request:

[image: Assignment output request]

```
import random

lucky_number = random.randint(1, 100)
while True:
    print("Guess our lucky number between <1> and <100>: ")
    try:
        user_number = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

        if user_guess < 1 or user_guess > 100:
            print("   The feasible range is between <> and <>. Try something more reasonable...")
        elif user_guess < lucky_number:
            print(f"    Your guess <{user_number}> is too small, try again!")
        elif user_guess > lucky_number:
            print(f"    Your guess <{user_number}> is too large, try again!")
        else:
            print(f"    Congratulations! <{user_number}> is our lucky number!")
            break
```

How can I let the number change after every guess to show the range become smaller in the queston

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i77397761/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why have a `try` with no actual handling of exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Just a fun version where you get six chances and can never win:

```py
print('You have six chances to guess my number.')
lo, hi = 1, 100
for i in range(6):
  g = int(input(f'Guess my number from {lo} to {hi}: '))
  if g < (lo + hi) / 2:
    print('too small')
    lo = g + 1
  else:
    print('too large')
    hi = g - 1
print(f'You failed! My number was {lo}.')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZA9TgMxEIVF61M8ROG1ksBupJBVRGoqDkBpgv8kr72yvUAU5SQ020DPdTgN3h8hIRpL4_nemzfz_tkek_au7z-6JFf198VVG4xLBX30HTR_EYjmDQfN3UFEJA_ViRjRHOG65kmEa8qI9Utogz2qJaqyJNIHGBiHwJ0SxS3bEUDl_mBsXNulQtL7vz6QwTc4WX8ehpy0Oe9AGctCI7P2DoX1WOQxDDdYD4bAnDR5j9hwaykbvzO4z5IFqlwKG8U_2vKgxEyPwRVWmZ4IOa4uubHi-RIPvwFfeRzz5Y2nW80n6782JdluSF2Tek22-S2nxg8)

Sample game:

```
You have six chances to guess my number.
Guess my number from 1 to 100: 50
too small
Guess my number from 51 to 100: 75
too small
Guess my number from 76 to 100: 88
too large
Guess my number from 76 to 87: 82
too large
Guess my number from 76 to 81: 78
too small
Guess my number from 79 to 81: 80
too large
You failed! My number was 79.
```

Answer (score 0):

this was quite a fun idea (and a decent first attempt) so i have posted an answer.

the key points are:

- initialise low and high points outside of the loop
- select the random number outside of the loop

Also, i fixed some of the variables which were not consistent.

finally, increment and decrement the low and high values after an incorrect guess is made.

```py
import random


low, high = 0, 100
lucky_number = random.randint(low, high)

while True:
    print(f"Guess our lucky number between {low} and {high}: ")

    user_number = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

    if user_number < low or user_number > high:
        print(f"   The feasible range is between {low} and {high}. Try something more reasonable...")
    elif user_number < lucky_number:
        print(f"    Your guess <{user_number}> is too small, try again!")
        low = user_number
    elif user_number > lucky_number:
        print(f"    Your guess <{user_number}> is too large, try again!")
        high = user_number
    else:
        print(f"    Congratulations! <{user_number}> is our lucky number!")
        break
```

here is an example of the output (on a game that i played) now:

```
Guess our lucky number between 0 and 100: 
    Your guess <50> is too small, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 50 and 100: 
    Your guess <75> is too large, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 50 and 75: 
    Your guess <75> is too large, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 50 and 75: 
    Your guess <60> is too large, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 50 and 60: 
    Your guess <60> is too large, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 50 and 60: 
    Your guess <55> is too small, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 55 and 60: 
    Your guess <57> is too large, try again!
Guess our lucky number between 55 and 57: 
    Congratulations! <56> is our lucky number!
```

Comment: This doesn't follow from the example image provided. The expected answer should have a guess that's too low become the new lower bound, and a guess that's too high become the new upper bound. you're always shifting the lower and upper bounds by 10, except when they reach the lucky number. Once you get to the step `22 and 70`, you know the lucky number has to be 23, since it's the lower bound + 1, since the lower bound is only not divisible by 10 near the answer, and same for the upper bound in other examples.

Comment: @Samathingamajig, yes, but this is just an example, so one can implement any variant on this theme.  For example, you could increment and decrement by random amounts.

Comment: @Samathingamajig,  i implemented the change that you suggested.  Now the guess forms the new boundary...  thanks for pointing this out !